# xterm colors are too bright

Tags: terminal, colors, xterm

I've just started using dwm a couple days ago and I'm using xterm (uxterm) as a terminal emulator.

However, I'm noticing that certain applications (like vi/vim, ls, and others) that output in color are using bright colors and (sometimes) bold fonts. My terminal's background color is a dark pastel so I'd like the colors to match.

How can I change these colors, is there a way to use #xxxxxx colors?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xterm is configured via [X resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). This is how you might configure it for white on black, with a lighter blue than the default (adjust the color as you see fit, obviously):

```
XTerm.VT100.background:         Black
XTerm.VT100.color0:             Black
XTerm.VT100.color1:             Red
XTerm.VT100.color2:             Green
XTerm.VT100.color3:             Yellow
XTerm.VT100.color4:             CornflowerBlue
XTerm.VT100.color5:             Magenta
XTerm.VT100.color6:             Cyan
XTerm.VT100.color7:             White
XTerm.VT100.colorBD:            White
XTerm.VT100.colorBDMode:        true
XTerm.VT100.colorUL:            Yellow
XTerm.VT100.colorULMode:        true
XTerm.VT100.cursorColor:        Red
XTerm.VT100.foreground:         White
```

You can use X color names (you can see all the color names with `xcolors` or in a file called `rgb.txt` which may be somewhere under `/etc/X11`, `/usr/X11` or `/usr/share/X11` or some similar location depending on your system) or `#RRGGBB`. `colorBD` is the color used for bold; with `colorBDMode` set to `false` (the default), this setting is ignored and bold text is displayed in a bold font. The same goes for `colorUL`, `colorULMode` and underline. You can go beyond `color8` (up to `color255`, or less depending on the xterm version and compile-time configuration). `color8` through `color15` correspond to 0–7 with bold; colors beyond 16 are rarely used by applications unless you've explicitly configured them.

Put these settings into a file called `~/.Xdefaults`. Most systems load this file automatically when you log in. If yours doesn't, add this command to your X startup script:

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults
```

To test the appearance of foreground color 42 over background color 17, run this in a shell in that terminal:

```
printf '\033[38;5;%dm\033[48;5;%dm%s\033[0m\n' 42 17 "Hello, world."
```

If your xterm is compiled without extended color support, you'll need to use the classical control sequences:

```
printf '\033[3%dm\033[4%dm%s\033[0m\n' 4 1 "Hello, world."
```

The foreground and background color must be in the range 0–7 in that case. If your xterm is compiled with 16-color support, replace `[3` and `[4` by `[9` and `[10` respectively to select the bright versions (colors 8–15).

Comment: I've been toying around with this and it seems to change the colors of `ls` you need to edit the `/etc/DIR_COLORS` file. I see color codes in here, but I'm only allowed a certain number of them. Namely, 42 doesn't work but instead gives me a green background.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by editing the `.Xdefaults` file in your home directory. You can just try some other people available `.Xdefaults` settings, like [this one](https://gist.github.com/564084) that uses "zenburn" dark color scheme. You'll use just the lines begining with "xterm". Just tested that it works this way for `uxterm` as well. If for some reason it doesn't for you, change the line beginnings to "uxterm".

Comment: When applying mentioned here `.Xdefaults` setting change, this article might help : http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/linux:change_xterm_to_white_on_black and here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdefaults_%28English%29#xterm_preferences

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are using dwm: you can also leave the X resources (as mentioned in the other answers) alone and instead modify the command that invokes the terminal. In my `config.h` I have modified the terminal command to read

```
static const char *termcmd[]  = { "uxterm", "+cm", "+dc", "-bg", "black", "-fg", "gold", NULL };
```

Which enables colors and uses gold on black See https://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm for the available options. (Notice that you have to recompile dwm after changing it's config.)

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

> How can I change these colors[?]

You can change these colors with an `.Xresources` file.

> [I]s there a way to use #xxxxxx colors?

Yes. For example `xterm*color1: ffa70a` ( though I don't suggest `lightsalmon` as your `xterm*color1` ). Note that, I imagine among other specifications, you can use an equivalent option - `xterm*color1: rgb:ff/a7/0a` - which I think is a bit more readable (especially for people just learning *NIX systems; if you feel better with the `#ffa70a`, feel free to use it).

An example of making all colors less bright than the defaults is:

```bsh
$ cd
$ test -f .Xresources && \
  cp .Xresources .Xresources.$(date '%s').bak \
  # backing up existing .Xresources if it exists
$ test -f .Xresources || touch .Xresources \
  # creating .Xresources if it doesn't exist
```

Edit `~/.Xresources` using your favorite editor For this example, the file should end up as

```
xterm*color1: gray40
xterm*color2: red5
xterm*color3: green5
xterm*color4: yellow5
xterm*color5: magenta5
xterm*color6: cyan5
xterm*color7: white5
xterm*color8: gray50
xterm*color9: red2
xterm*color10: green2
xterm*color11: yellow2
xterm*color13: magenta2
xterm*color14: cyan2
xterm*color15: white2
```

Run

```bsh
$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Then, your

`$ xterm &`

should bring up something less bright.

I should mention one resource in the TL;DR, because it has been so useful for me with `xterm`, etc.

[Thomas E. Dickey's Invisible Island: XTerm FAQs](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html)

---

#### Details

@Gilles_'SO-_stop_being_evil' has a great answer - I especially liked the information on how to preview a color from the terminal with `printf` and the escapes for the ascii color codes.

The answer from @Gilles helped me to find out how to fix **my** too-bright XTerm stuff. The part that was bothering me was the bright green of the `<username>@<machine-name>`. (See Note {1} for my reasons not to have a screenshot.) I wasn't able to get the change using any of the listed colors, and I didn't really understand how to use the info that

> If your xterm is compiled with 16-color support, replace [3 and [4 by [9 and [10 respectively to select the bright versions (colors 8–15).

I was led to look at the [documentation from X.org](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/xterm.1.html#:%7E:text=color0%20%28class%20Color0%29). If that previous link, which points to

`https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/xterm.1.html#:~:text=color0%20%28class%20Color0%29`

doesn't take you to the part of the page with "color0 (class Color0)", then do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>
for "color0 (class Color0)". In the docs, there's nothing listed after `color0`-`color6`, but after `color7` one can read

> These specify the colors for the ISO-6429 extension. The defaults are, respectively, ...

After this, the colors match the table from @Gilles, but I show what's in the docs. I repeat it to give a second way of seeing it, as well as to add emphasis with bold text and notes I've added inside square brackets.

> ... The defaults are, respectively, 
> **black** [meaning `color0`], 
> **red3** [meaning `color1`], 
> **green3** [`color2`], 
> **yellow3** [`color3`], 
> **DodgerBlue1** [`color4`],
>     **[** *Note that* `linux.die.net/man/1/xterm` *and* 
>                         `man xterm | grep -B9 -A32 color4` 
>       *both list 'a customizable dark blue'* 
>       *for what matches with* `color4`. **]**
> **magenta3** [`color5`],
> **cyan3** [`color6`],
> and **gray90** [`color7`].

For the RGB (or other color-space) coordinates of these named colors, find `X11`'s `rgb.txt` using `find /usr/share/ -type f -name "rgb.txt" 2>&1 | grep -i "X11"`, or, if that doesn't work, `find /usr/ -type f -name "rgb.txt" 2>&1 | grep -i "X11"`. I've seen a lot of resources that list it at `/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/rgb.txt`, but on my machine (see Note 2) it's at `/usr/share/X11/rgb.txt`.

Further, there's nothing listed after `color8`-`color14`, but after `color15` one can read

> These specify the colors for the ISO-6429 extension if the bold attribute is also enabled.  The default resource values are respectively, 
> **gray30** [`color8`], 
> **red** [`color9`], 
> **green** [`color10`], 
> **yellow** [`color11`], 
> **SteelBlue1** [`color12`],
>     **[** *Note that* `linux.die.net/man/1/xterm` *and* 
>                         `man xterm | grep -m1 -B34 -A5 color15` 
>       *both list 'a customizable light blue'* 
>       *for what matches with* `color12`. **]**
> **magenta** [`color13`],
> **cyan** [`color14`],
> and **white** [`color15`].

As for 'if the bold attribute is enabled', this is the case unless you've changed the defaults, for example by adding `xterm*boldMode: false` to your `.Xresources` or `.Xdefaults`.

With all this information, I was able to fix my too-bright-green problem by making an `.Xresources` file in my home directory ( `cd` ; `touch .Xresources` ). I chose this instead of `.Xdefaults`, because I read somewhere that `.Xdefaults` is deprecated. I don't have the source for that, sadly. Then, I added the line,

`xterm*color10: green2`

(`green2` is less bright that `green` and more bright than `green3`)

and running

`xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

To make the other bold colors less bright, one could have in one's `.Xresources` the following:

```
xterm*color8: gray20
xterm*color9: red2
xterm*color10: green2
xterm*color11: yellow2
xterm*color13: magenta2
xterm*color14: cyan2
xterm*color15: white2
```

You could also make *everything* less bright by doing something like `xterm*color3: green3` with `xterm*color10:green6`, etc. for the other pairs of colors.

You can also use hex ( `#xxxxxx` ) and RGB decimal values. I don't doubt that you can use other specifications of colors, too. So, in answer to your questions:

> How can I change these colors, is there a way to use #xxxxxx colors?

You can change these colors with an `.Xresources` file.

AND

You can use `#xxxxxx` colors with, e.g. `xterm*color10: #00ee00`

(respectively).

---

**Notes**:
{1} I would post a screenshot, but as of now (2021-12-23), StackExchange sites seem to be having trouble with attached images, and I can't put a backup from the Wayback Machine here at work.
{2} The following command and output show my machine information. I'm running RHEL 8, RHEL standing for **R**ed **H**at **E**nterprise **L**inux.

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux MYMACHINE 4.18.0-240.10.1.el8_3.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 16 03:30:52 EST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

**Other useful resources**:
[Color names and locations in color spaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man3/Color::Library::Dictionary::X11.3pm.html)
[An SO answer that has useful comments describing what certain `color[1]?[0-9]` will affect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37703709/6505499)
[ArchLinux:  Understanding Xdefault terminal colors](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=132593)
[What are the colors[0..15] used for in xterm?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539430/291375)
[Examples of application-specific .xresources](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa98de9fd70b51611303)
[AstroBetter - Customizing xTerm and Terminal: colors](https://www.astrobetter.com/blog/2010/08/25/xterm-color/) , be careful to back up your `LS_COLORS` environment variable, e.g. `echo $LS_COLORS > ~/.env_LS_COLORS.$(date +'%s').bak` before trying these things.
[Very close to what I ended up using](https://unix4lyfe.org/xterm/), note that this disables the bold, as I ended up doing.
Perhaps the most useful: [Thomas E. Dickey's Invisible Island: XTerm FAQs](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html)