# Understanding colors in zsh

Tags: zsh, colors

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159856/how-do-zsh-ansi-colour-codes-work/6159885#6159885), yoda suggests the following solution for using colors in `zsh`

```
#load colors
autoload colors && colors
for COLOR in RED GREEN YELLOW BLUE MAGENTA CYAN BLACK WHITE; do
    eval $COLOR='%{$fg_no_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}'  #wrap colours between %{ %} to avoid weird gaps in autocomplete
    eval BOLD_$COLOR='%{$fg_bold[${(L)COLOR}]%}'
done
eval RESET='$reset_color'
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but if I understand correctly, `autoload colors && colors` allows you to call colors by their name, while the rest of the script just wraps them in `${ $}`.

This made me think about the following questions:

1. Is there a way to know what colors are loaded by calling `autoload colors && colors`?
2. How do I know what colors are supported by my terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `colors` function records the names of colors and similar attributes (bold, underline and so on) in the associative array `color`. This array associates names with terminal attribute strings, which are numbers, e.g. `00` ↔ `normal`, `42` ↔ `bg-green`, …

```
echo ${(o)color}
```

If you want to see how the array is built, look at the source of the function: `which colors` or `less $^fpath/colors(N)`.

The `colors` function only defines names and escape strings (in the associative arrays `fg` and `bg`) for the 8 standard colors. Your terminal may have more. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18803/xterm-colors-are-too-bright/18806#18806) for how to explore what colors are available.