# What are the colors[0..15] used for in xterm?

Tags: linux, colors, xterm

In the configuration files of XTerm (e.g. `/usr/share/X11/app-defaults/` or `~/.Xresources`) you can configure values for the variables `color[o..15]`. The question is: **What is colorX used for?**

So far I found at http://www.futurile.net/2016/06/15/xterm-256color-themes-molokai-terminal-theme/

`color0` - background (Note: There is also a setting for the "background" color)

`color1` - foreground, standard files (Note: There is also a setting for the "foreground" color)

`color2` - world writable directories

`color3` - fifo files

`color4` - unused?

`color5` - unused?

`color6` - unused?

`color7` - setuid file

`color8` - unused?

`color9` - orphaned soft links, gzipped files

`color10` - executable binaries

`color11` - block special files

`color12` - Directories

`color13` - socket file

`color14` - symbolic link

`color15` - background color, setuid

I cannot fully confirm these.

Comment: When to use a specific color depends on the application, not terminal emulator

Comment: Those are the colors which will be turned on by the `\e[3Xn` (foreground) and `\e[4Xn` (background)  "ansi color escapes". For instance, if you run xterm as `xterm -xrm '*VT100.color1: green3'`, a `printf '\e[41mFOO\e[m\n'` inside the terminal will print `FOO` with its background green instead of red.